# What techniques can help me identifying unused dependencies for a production build?

Tags: node.js, dependencies, typescript

I have certain dependencies in my project like sequelize-auto which are not required in production, since we only need to generate the models once during development. Even if we make changes to the database, we won't need to use sequelize-auto again in production.

In my package.json file, I can make a distinction between [devDependencies and dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file). But how can I identify in a reliable fashion which dependencies are only required during development, and which are required during production?

I'm new for this and completely lost on it. I would appreciate any recommendations for solutions.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Either your project uses them or else it doesn't - what difference does it make whether it's in one place or several?

Comment: What does it mean to be "used once"? Imported once? A function called once? Always called in the same way, from the same place, but maybe multiple times?

Comment: @KilianFoth When I said 'once,' I meant that after deploying the project to production, we wouldn't need to use tools like sequelize-auto again. We only need to generate the models once during development. Even if we make changes to the database, we won't need to use sequelize-auto again in production

Comment: So it's really about development dependencies vs. runtime dependencies? I'm no Javascript wonk, but I know other build systems have this distinction and I expect Javascript does too.

Comment: @SelloBello106 Please [edit your question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/449068/edit) to include the scope change from your comment.

Comment: `devDependencies` vs. `dependencies`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes

Comment: @PhilipKendall: I took the freedom to help the OP to get their question in shape. If you think it resolves the issues, consider to help reopening it.

Comment: Reopened and up-voted. This is, IMO, perfectly on-topic for this community.

Comment: The dependencies are always installed, the dev dependencies are dependencies required for local use, for example testing.  For example, one would not want to install JEST (testing framework) on production machine since tests are not run on production, so that is the distinction between the two dependency trees in package.json.

Comment: Also, engineers can inadvertently install dependencies but not reference them, thus they will still exist on the deployment and then your application has a larger service area for vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dev Dependencies are only installed when doing a full `npm install` (usually locally).  These usually include testing type of dependencies or other dependencies only needed for the local development environment.

By running `run npm install --production` during the production pipeline build will only install the dependencies and not the Dev Dependencies in package.json.  These dependencies are the ones required for your deployed package to run correctly.

To see if you have dependencies that are not used, you can use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/depcheck  (depcheck) to remove dependencies that are not used.  This will make your deployed packages smaller.  Also, please note there are other tools out there as well to manage un-used dependencies.

Sometimes, Dev Dependencies end up in the Dependency tree used for production builds.  In these cases, simply move the dependency to a Dev Dependency and it will no longer be included in the production build.  NPM installs without the `--production` flag will still install it for local (non-production) use.

Comment: Here's a reference link as well...  https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file